# Firebase UseEffect

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, use-effect

So I have some code here, which is supposed to automatically run whenever the firebase server updates:

```
//Whenever the firebase database changes, it runs this method
    useEffect(() => {
        db.collection("posts").orderBy("timestamp", "desc").onSnapshot((snapshot) =>
            //Loops through all the posts and adds the data into an array
          setPosts(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()))
        );
      }, []);
```

But how does it know that the database updated? I thought that useEffect only ran whenever the screen rendered, so how does it know to run when the database gets updated?

Comment: From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) `If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument. This tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props or state, so it never needs to re-run.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in concept similar to how your event handlers work.

Consider this :-

```
  useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('scroll',handleScroll);
      }, []);
```

In the above code the handler get's registered only once due to that `[]` dependency array which makes the effect only runs once post first render.
But for each scroll, the `handleScroll` will trigger because it's **registered**.

Similarly in your case, `onSnapshot` is that event listener which got registered for you but yes if you were to log the react state inside this `onSnapshot` callback, you will see the stale one (the state you set initially - could be empty array in your case) due to closure. Here in your case your are simply getting the latest content from `onSnapshot` callback's first parameter i.e `snapshot` and setting it to your state so it's all working good.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, can you please explain what "registered" means? And how do you know that .onSnapshot is registered, why can't .orderBy be registered?

Comment: @TarunRavi So when I say **registered**, it means that whenever the event executes, the respective event listener will fire the supplied logic. I know `.onSnapshot` is registered because it's mentioned in the docs that it's a realtime event listener. Meanwhile `orderBy` is just a normal function which takes the `posts` collection as input and performs the operation. For browser event listener , refer this - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events
For firestore `onSnapshot`, refer this - https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen